# React update struggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have struggle to understand how to update React state -> $push and $unshift..

My state looks like: `data = { 2: [1, 2, 3], 7: [5, 3, 4] }`

And I need to update records specific object key with variable and delete or add element into that array.. I've tried something like:

`var elem_id = this.props.elem_id;
var newArray = update(data, {elem_id: {$push: [4]}});
var newArray = update(data, {elem_id: {$unshift: [4]}});`

But unsuccessfully what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `data[elem_id].push(4);`?

Comment: This data is a state

Comment: `var data = this.state.data; data[elem_id].push(4); this.setState({data: data});`

Comment: And deleting and element?

Comment: I've tried with splice but it has odd behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newArray = update(data, {elem_id: {$push: [4]}});
```

will try to push `4` onto an array at the literal key `elem_id`; that is to say, `elem_id` is an object literal key, and is *not* replaced with the contents of the *variable* `elem_id`.

If you're using a transpiler that supports ES6's computed property syntax (like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/)), you could do the following:

```
var newArray = update(data, {[elem_id]: {$push: [4]}});
```

If you're not, you'll have to *create* the object and then *set* the operation:

```
var toUpdate = {};
toUpdate[elem_id] = {$push: [4]};
var newArray = update(data, toUpdate);
```

Comment: Note that this does not work with the standard JSX transformer.

Comment: That's correct, computed properties aren't supported by the JSX transformer, but [JSTransform is being deprecated](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) in favor of other tools (like Babel) anyway.